# paperclip with ruby 1.9.2-p180

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, ruby-1.9.2

I am trying to update my Rails 3 application to use ruby 1.9.2

The problem is paperclip stops creating attachments / styles for my uploads and only uploads the original.

I am using rails 3.0.7 and paperclip 2.3.11

This all works switching to 1.8.7 via RVM.

Does paperclip work with 1.9.2 ?
Has anyone got it working ?

Please help with advice / fixes / solutions.

thanks a lot in advance
Rick

Comment: Look into your logs and show us errors or any lines about paperclip

Comment: in the logs there is    conversion of image into different sizes like so :

Comment: [paperclip] identify -format %wx%h '/var/folders/z+/z+KzOZBFE9irCpbMKKBGFk+++TI/-Tmp-/stream20110508-80725-1290zpt-0.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] convert '/var/folders/z+/z+KzOZBFE9irCpbMKKBGFk+++TI/-Tmp-/stream20110508-80725-1290zpt-0.jpg[0]' -resize "200x200>" '/var/folders/z+/z+KzOZBFE9irCpbMKKBGFk+++TI/-Tmp-/stream20110508-80725-1290zpt-020110508-80725-jlxg4i-0' 2>/dev/null

Comment: on 1.8.7 but nothing on 1.9.2.    Also on 1.8.7 its says saving the different attachemnts but on 1.9.2 just says saving original attachement.      any idea?    no errors in dev.log

Comment: I have paperclip working on 1.9.2-p180, Rails 3.0.4, Paperclip 2.3.8. Thought I'd upgrate rails one of these days, but not got around to it yet, so I can't tell if it's the newer versions that causes your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am running paperclip on ruby 1.9.2 so must be your code.

Please strip back code to bare minimal and test then gradually add untill it breaks.

hope this helps